# in iOS 11 the keyboard autocorrect creates invalid UTF8

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ios11

Our app accepts user text input which we then save to a server-side database.
In iOS 11 when you enter two "-" characters in a row they are automatically combined into an emdash (—). When you enter three "-" characters in a row you end up with an emdash + a half emdash which has an invalid terminator. 
This is causing issues for my rails server which cannot parse this string because it is invalid. 
The string looks like this: \xE2\x80\x94\x00

Comment: Is this only an iOS 11 problem?

Comment: Yes, only in iOS 11 does the keyboard do this type of replacement. In iOS 10 it stays as 3 dashes.

Comment: This sounds like a coding mismatch. You should be able to set client side encoding so that postgresql converts to whatever its internal encoding is on the fly. Look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/multibyte.html#AEN39240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Smart dashes' as it is called, is the process is converting two/three dashes to a single larger dash. This is only available from iOS 11. It can be controlled using [smartDashesType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2866013-smartdashestype) which is a part of the [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits?language=swift) protocol.