# iOS how to stop text field convert "--" to "—"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

When type two "-" in text field, it automatically become "—", how to programmatically stop UITextField convert "--" to "—".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47022956/1187415.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITextField` has a `smartDashes` property: set it to `.no`. You can do this via InterfaceBuilder (in the text field's *Attributes Inspector* look for the *Smart Quotes* drop-down), or programatically:

```
textField.smartDashesType = .no
```

Comment: For OC, it is `textField.smartDashesType = UITextSmartDashesTypeNo; `